# SQL query to linq (with/as, update)

Tags: sql, linq

I have difficulties and struggle in changing SQL query to linq.

Here is one of my example code:

```
string sql = "WITH cte as 
(SELECT TOP(1) PART_ID 
FROM [History] 
WHERE PART_ID = '' AND CURRENT_WEIGHT is NULL) 
UPDATE cte 
SET PART_ID = @PART_ID";
```

Here what I have done for a part:

```
db.Histories
   .Select(u => new
   {
       u.PartId,
       u.CurrentWeight
   })
   .Where(u => u.PartId == "")
   .Where(u => u.CurrentWeight == null)
   .Take(1);
```

I have no idea to change the with cte as, update statement. Hope to receive some helps. Thank you.

Comment: You can't. LINQ doesn't update, it's a query language. You can change the properties of a `History` object (remove the `Select` part), and then save it.

Comment: You can do that only by [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
var history = db.Histories
    .Where(u => u.PartId == "" && u.CurrentWeight == null).Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
history.PartId = newValue;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This will not work, because `.Take` returns a list, not a single object.